# print select value from json object

Tags: c#, json, console, json.net, foursquare

How do i print out a selected field from my json object without having to create classes for it, at the moment it prints out the whole json object but i just want to print out selected fields for example something like Console.WriteLine(response.venues.name);

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace FourSquareTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&query=mcdonalds&client_id=XXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXX&v=20120101");
            // Now parse with JSON.Net

            JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
            foreach (var pair in parsed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);

            }

        }


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
 JToken response = parsed["response"];
 JArray venues = (JArray)response["venues"];
 JValue names = (JValue)venues[1]["name"];
```

But I don't have the library to test, so that's just based on the documentation.

Comment: oops i forgot to add "using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject;" but now it gets an error Identifier Expected

Comment: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, it was Item not Items, fixed. I'm just referencing http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: i am still getting the same error above but 'Item' instead of 'Items'

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: I had the syntax a bit wrong. Try something like this. (edited above)

Comment: Thankyou Corylulu you are the best :)